# Why does the sequence operator 0-2:-4 lead to -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4?

Tags: r, sequence

Typing in `0-2:-4` returns `[1] -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4` in the console. Can anyone explain the logic behind this?

Comment: It's in the R-FAQ (sort of): See section 7.33 and ?Syntax. Your expression is being interpreted as  0 minus  seq( 2, -4). The unary "-"-operator has higher precedence than the "colon" and the colon ":"-operator has higher precedence than a binary minus.

Comment: Just a general note - if you something isn't doing what you expect and you post here it wouldn't hurt to tell us what you expect.  I see your code and know how R deals with these things so in my mind it looks exactly like it should.  This is a simple example and it's easy enough to figure out what you probably intended it to do but if you're asking a question it is a good idea to clarify what your expectations were.

Answer (score 7):

Because of the order of operation:

```
0 - (2:-4)
```

which expands to

```
0 - c(2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4)
```

See `?Syntax` for more details, including a complete list of binary operators in order of precedence.

Comment: Good edit, thanks @Gregor. (Don't think I've actually read that page yet ... :-)